# trino gives zstd invalid magic prefix?

Tags: hadoop, presto, trino, zstd

I ve kerberized hive and hdfs

Trino version 422
Hadoop 3.3.4

I ve zst files on hdfs and when i try to query that table include zst files it gives this error

```
Trino gives error invalid magic prefix offset 16
```

The file is not corrupted , how can i solve this issue